# MySQL - CodeIgniter Fails to Interpolate Query Parameters

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Ok I'm running a query and CodeIgniter is giving me this error:

> Error Number: 1064
>
> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '' at line 4
>
> SELECT username FROM friend_request JOIN user ON user_id = friend
>   WHERE (friend = '8' AND sender =

I do realize, it's not catching the sender, HOWEVER $this->session->userdata('user_id') echos to be 4 (which is my user_id)...
So how come it's not showing up as anything?

```
$this->db->query('SELECT username
    FROM friend_request
    JOIN user ON user_id = friend
    WHERE (friend = ? AND sender = ?)
    OR (friend = ? AND sender = ?)', 
        $user->row()->user_id, 
        $this->session->userdata('user_id'), 
        $this->session->userdata('user_id'), 
        $user->row()->user_id);

if($this->db->num_rows() > 0) {
    $this->errors->set_error('You either have a pending request from '.ucfirst($this->db->row()->username).' 
        or you have already requested their friendship!');
    return false;
}
```

I tried putting everything on one line because I didn't know if the enters would break anything, but it still didn't fix any of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get an error because you should use the `num_rows` on the query result, not on the database. Also, you query binding is wrong.

```
$query = $this->db->query(
  'SELECT username
  FROM friend_request
  JOIN user ON user_id = friend
  WHERE (friend = ? AND sender = ?)
  OR (friend = ? AND sender = ?)', 
  array(
    $user->row()->user_id, 
    $this->session->userdata('user_id'), 
    $this->session->userdata('user_id'), 
    $user->row()->user_id
  )
);

if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
    $this->errors->set_error('You either have a pending request from '.ucfirst($this->db->row()->username).' 
        or you have already requested their friendship!');
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Fatal error: Call to undefined method CI_DB_mysql_driver::num_rows() in H:\WD SmartWare.swstor\HALEY-HP\Source\DStable\dragon\models\user_model.php on line 351

I did try that before posting this! I guess I should have included that.